# Generate random and if not exist in DB,add it

Tags: php

I'm almost there,but something is missing.My PHP app:

1)User is requesting to the server

2)The server is generating a long unique string and checks if exists in the DB:If YES then generate again(until it doesn't exists),if NO then add it to the DB and finish. All logic should be executed with a single request,i.e user should not request/refresh page if generated string exist.

I am stuck in the YES part.

My code (**DISCLAIMER**:I do not own parts of the following code)

```
 <?php
    class genPass
    {
    private $db;
        function __construct() {
            $this->db=new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
                $this->db->set_charset("utf8");
            $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
        }
        function __destruct() {
            $this->db->close();
        }  

    function isUsed($uid)
    {
        $stmt=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM id WHERE udid='".$uid."'")or die($this->db->error);

        while($stmt->num_rows <1) {
        $newnum = $this->generateStrongPassword();
        $newcheck=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM id WHERE udid='".$newnum."'")or die($this->db->error);

        if ($newcheck->num_rows >= 1) {
            echo $newnum . " exists! \n";  <- WHAT TO DO IF EXISTS?WHICH PART OF THE SCRIPT SHOULD I RUN AGAIN
        } else {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO id (udid) VALUES ('".$newnum."')")or die($this->db->error);
            echo "$newnum - CAN ISNERT@!@!@";
            break;
        }
    }

    }
    public function generateStrongPassword($length = 3, $add_dashes = false, $available_sets = 'lu')
    {
        $sets = array();
        if(strpos($available_sets, 'l') !== false)
            $sets[] = 'ab';//'abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
        if(strpos($available_sets, 'u') !== false)
            $sets[] = 'AB';//'ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        if(strpos($available_sets, 'd') !== false)
            $sets[] = '23456789';
        if(strpos($available_sets, 's') !== false)
            $sets[] = '!@#$%&*?';

        $all = '';
        $password = '';
        foreach($sets as $set)
        {
            $password .= $set[array_rand(str_split($set))];
            $all .= $set;
        }

        $all = str_split($all);
        for($i = 0; $i < $length - count($sets); $i++)
            $password .= $all[array_rand($all)];

        $password = str_shuffle($password);

        if(!$add_dashes)
            return $password;

        $dash_len = floor(sqrt($length));
        $dash_str = '';
        while(strlen($password) > $dash_len)
        {
            $dash_str .= substr($password, 0, $dash_len) . '-';
            $password = substr($password, $dash_len);
        }
        $dash_str .= $password;
        return $this->$dash_str;
    }
    }


    $obj = new genPass;
    $ran=$obj->generateStrongPassword();
    $obj->isUsed($ran);

    ?>
```

Comment: This code looks just bad. Just one example: `isUsed` function... that returns nothing? Even if it did return something, what would be the point of running a loop and checking more uids? The caller is obviously only interested in the one uid they passed in!

Comment: Jon,look at the code and this line `echo "$newnum - CAN ISNERT@!@!@";`,this one is the response!!!!

Comment: Live example: http://codepad.org/NMmNkBFw

Comment: You can try MySQL's `UUID()` function.

Comment: Ah... the PHP-FIG standards are a wonderful thing... as are access modifiers, if used consistently... Single responsability principle... closing `?>`... where do I start? this code violates so many principles/conventions, it's hard to even begin to think about attempting to work out what it does, and what it's meant to do

Comment: @Theodoros80: if a function echoes something, it still doesn't _return_ anything. The echo is a language construct, that passes a string to the output

Comment: I am not getting and error.Please read my problem.I want to re-generate and start the loop again if the string exists in the DB.

Comment: @Theodoros80: Elias is talking about this: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/ , http://www.php-fig.org/psr/1/ , http://www.php-fig.org/psr/2/ and http://www.php-fig.org/psr/3/

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem What SOLID principles have to do with PSR standarts?

Comment: @DaveJust: Nothing, really... it's just that the code in the question was violating SOLID principles, FIG standards, it's inconsistent, badly indented, and as a result just looks a right mess, IMO. I had to get that off of my chest before I could actually get down to writing a decent answer

Comment: Note that passwords (as named by your function) should never be saved as is in a database. Also, if two users run your code simultaneously (two people who access the site at the same time) the code can fails and generate the same password twice.

Comment: well the passwords are there for speed.I know and i practise storing passwords to a separate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a function `isUsed()`, which is good, but I'd suggest limiting that function to checking if the random key is used or not.

```
function isUsed($uid)
{
    $stmt=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM id WHERE udid='".$uid."'")or die($this->db->error);
    if ($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        // Already a duplicate key, so should return TRUE for sure!!!
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

That way, you could use a loop to check:

```
while $obj->isUsed($ran) {
    $ran = $obj->generateStrongPassword();
}
// put pwd in database after this loop!
```

By the way, this is just to explain the logic that has to be used... Check your code for further inconsistencies... :-)

Comment: Why is `isUsed` longer than one line? Why does it generate a password again? Copy/pasting from a bad source is going to leave you with a bad result.

Comment: @Theodoros80: Be weary of the fact that `isUsed` is _public_, and that, when passing unsantized data to it, your system is vulnerable to injection attacks, as you're just blindly stringing the passed argument to the query, and thus the DB

Comment: Thank you Elias! For sure i will consider making my script safer and more "PHP-FIG" standard! I didm't know that a simple question about this,would raise such comments!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll bite:

```
class GenPass
{
    private $isUsedStmt = null;
    private $db = null;
    //constructor etc...
    /**
     * Works like most hashtables: re-hashes $id param until a unique hash is found
     * uses sha256 algo, currently, no hash-collisions have been found, so pretty solid
     * you could change to sha512, but that would be overkill
     * @return string
     **/
    public function insertUniqueRandom($id = null)
    {
        $id = $id ? $id : $this->getRandomId();
        do
        {//use hashes, rehash in case of collision
            $id = hash('256', $id);
        }while($this->isUsed($id));
        //once here, current $id hash has no collisions
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO `id` (udid) VALUES ("'.$id.'")');
        return $id;//returns unique has that has been found & used/storred
    }
    /**
     * Random string generator... returns random string
     * of specfied $length (default 10)
     * @param int $length = 10
     * @return String
     **/
    public function getRandomId($length = 10)
    {
        $length = (int) ($length > 1 ? $length : 10);
        $src = '0`12345~6789abc2%def&gh$ijklm!nopq?,rs><tuvwxyz';
        $out ='';
        for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++)
        {
            $char = $src{mt_rand(0, strlen($src))};
            $out .= $p%2 ? strtoupper($char) : $char;
        }
        return $out;
    }
    /**
     * Check if current hash already exists in DB, if so, return false, if not, return true
     * @return Boolean
     * @throws RuntimeException
     **/
    private function isUsed($uid)
    {
        $stmt = $this->getCheckUidStmt();
        $stmt->bindParam('s', $uid);
        if ($stmt->execute)
        {
            return $stmt->num_rows === 0 ? false : true;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException('failed to query for uid usage: '.$this->db->error);
    }
    /**
     * Lazy-load isUsed's prepared statement
     * The statement won't be prepared, unless the isUsed function is called
     * @return \mysqli::prepare
     **/
    private function getCheckUidStmt()
    {
        if ($this->isUsedStmt === null)
        {
            $this->isUsedStmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT udid FROM `id` WHERE udid = ?');
        }
        return $this->isUsedStmt;
    }
}
```

This is, as the comments say, how most hashtables work anyway: hash a random value, if that hash is already being used, simply hash the duplicate hash again, until that hash is not being used anywhere.
Usage:

```
$gen = new GenPass;
$usedID = $gen->insertUniqueRandom();
echo $usedID, ' was just inserted';
$another = $gen->insertUniqueRandom('foobar');//works, 
echo $another;//will echo:
//c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c8974e592c2fa383d4a3960714caef0c4f2
$foobarAgain = $gen->insertUniqueRandom('foobar');
echo $foobarAgain;//foobar already existed, now this will echo:
//181cd581758421220b8c53d143563a027b476601f1a837ec85ee6f08c2a82cad
```

As you can see, trying to insert "foobar" twice will result in 2 unique id's. What's more, the length of a sha256 hash is a given: its 256 bits long, or 64 chars, so that makes it easy to store in a DB: `VARCHAR(64)` is what you need... easy!
All things considered, I think it fair to say that this is probably the closest you'll get to a reliable, reasonably fast unique-random-id-generator you're going to get

Comment: Since your class does computations and manages storage logic, it violates the SRP. Why not to wrap storage logic inside separated `dataMapper`? Also have you heard about PoLS? And what it has to do with getters/setters?

Comment: @DaveJust: Aw please... Do you really expect me to write an entire _layer_ as an answer? I don't know what the bigger picture is here, So I stuck to the task at hand, and wrote some snippet as clean as possible, without taking it too far. Why don't you take the time and explain everything to the OP, put together a couple of gists, one focussing on IoC, the other more of a DI approach... perhaps set up a third using a framework, for good measure... Yes, I may have vented some frustration in my comment to the OP's question, but at least I then put in the effort, posting an answer to try and help