# Generate a unique number and make sure it doesn't exist

Tags: php, loops

I am generating a unique number like this:

`$unique_number = rand(100000000, 999999999);`

And I can check if it exists or not like this:

```
$exists = $this->count_rows('table', "WHERE unique_number=" . $unique_number . "');
```

and then:

`if ($exists >0){
 echo 'It exists. Generate it again';
 }`

The problem is ...how do I loop it until I get a number that does NOT exist? In case of the rare event that the one I generate exists already.

Comment: Why not just use AUTO_INCREMENT from your db?!?

Comment: I don't want it to be sequential :)

Comment: *You're thirsty in the desert; someone wants to give you water and you say: I only want cola* ?! Why? Does this have any reason that it can't be sequential ?

Comment: Yes, there is, otherwise I wouldn't ask for it ;)

Comment: This is a really stupid way to do what you're trying to do, then. Worst case, the loop could run forever. It'd be better to generate a list of number *in order*, then shuffle it. Look up a shuffling algorithm. At the very least, you could have a list in order, then generate a random number for each (not unique though). Select the list, but order by the random column.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 while($exists >0){
          $exists = $this->count_rows('table', "WHERE unique_number=" . $unique_number . "');
    }
```

Comment: A [`do-while`](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) might be better in this case. Also, need to generate a new number in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this

```
$exists = 1;   
while($exists > 0) {

 $unique_number = rand(100000000, 999999999);
 $exists = $this->count_rows('table', "WHERE unique_number=" . $unique_number . "');

}
```

Not tested

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  function check_number(){

    $unique_number = rand(100000000, 999999999);
    $exists = $this->count_rows('table', "WHERE unique_number=" . $unique_number);



    if ($exists >0){
        $results = check_number();
    }
     else{
            $results = $unique_number;
        return $results;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a class or function that will check if the number exisits in DB: if yes generate another one till its no then add to DB see smilar question :

[Generate random and if not exist in DB,add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212356/generate-random-and-if-not-exist-in-db-add-it)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of other way its just an idea hope it may help you.

If you loop through to check if the number is existing in the Table it will cost you

1. If you have data around 10000 it may run so fast
2. If you have data around 100000 it will cost you

If you can increase the number of count to 14

This will surely help you

Try generating random number from time

```
 $unique_number = microtime(true) * 10000;
```

This will be unique

You need not loop through to check if the random number is unique in database.

This is just and idea. Think it may help you achieve your goal.